# Quick help changing color of bar in html email signature

Tags: html, html-email

I have a very basic issue, but my html skills are limited.  I have html code for an email signature below. I am trying to change the color of the vertical bar to the same color gray as the name. I can't locate the bar. Thanks

```
<html>

<head>
<base target="_blank">
<style>
<!--
p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
{margin-top:0cm;
margin-right:0cm;
margin-bottom:0.0pt;
margin-left:0cm;
font-size:10.0pt;
font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";}
.Section1 p {
font-size: 9px;
font-weight: normal;
}
.disclaimer {
font-weight: bold;
 }
 -->
</style>

</head>

<body lang=EN-IN link=blue vlink=purple>

<div class=Section1>

<table class=MsoTableGrid border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0
 style='border-collapse:collapse;border:none'>
 <tr>
  <td width=274 valign=center style='width:152.4pt;border:none;border-
right:solid #414141 2.25pt;
  padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt'>
  <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0cm;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
  normal'><a href="http://www.casesbysource.com/"><span 
style='color:windowtext;text-decoration:none'><img border=0 width=202 height=62 
style="width:202px; height:62px" id="Picture 0"
  src="https://s4.postimg.org/cq9ledh4t/CBS-email-sig.jpg" alt="logo.jpg">
 </span></a></p>
  </td>
  <td width=338 valign=top style='width:202.5pt;border:none;padding:0cm 
5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt'>
  <table class=MsoTableGrid border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0
   style='border-collapse:collapse;border:none'>
   <tr>
    <td width=153 valign=top style='width:92.05pt;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm'>
    <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0cm;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    line-height:normal'><span style='font-size:12.0pt;color:#414141'>Mark 
DiSilvestro</span></p>
    <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0cm;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
line-height:normal'><span style='font-size:10pt; color:#1B3967'>COO</span>
</p>
    </td>
    <td width=154 valign=top style='width:92.15pt;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm'>
    <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0cm;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    line-height:normal'>&nbsp;</p>
    <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0cm;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    line-height:normal'>&nbsp;</p>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0cm;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
  normal'><span class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0cm;margin-
bottom:.0001pt;
    line-height:normal"><span style="font-size: 10pt; color: #414141">201-529-1069</span></span></p>
  <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0cm;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
  normal'><span style='font-size:10pt; color:#1B3967'><a
  href="http://www.casesbysource.com" style="text-decoration:none"><span 
style='color:#1B3967; text-decoration:
  none; font-size: 10pt;'>www.casesbysource.com</span></a><br>
215 Island Road, Mahwah, NJ 07430</span></p></tr>
  </table>
  <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0cm;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
  normal'></p>
  <p><br><br>
  </p>
  <p>
 <span class="disclaimer" span style='font-size:7.0pt; color:#000000; font-weight: normal;'>This e-mail is intended only for the addressee(s) and may contain confidential information.   If you are not the intended recipient, you are hereby notified that any use of this information or dissemination, distribution, or copying of this e-mail is strictly prohibited.  If you have received this e-mail in error, please notify the sender immediately by return e-mail and delete the original message.thank you</span>
</td>
 </tr>
</table>

<p class=MsoNormal>&nbsp;</p>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Add an  <hr/> tag after the <table>  or Try using an online wyswyg html editor to get it done

Comment: @VinodSrivastav the OP is talking about vertical line, hr is horizontal. Also a signature created in WYSIWYG is never recommended as its supposed to be coded like emails not as a webpage.

Comment: @Syfer Oh.. my bad

Comment: Hi, did the solution work?

Answer (score 0):

The vertical bar the border at line 32 look for `border-right:solid #414141 2.25pt;`. You have a line break after `border-` and its breaking the syntax.

The color is the same color gray as the name but since the padding is wide and the font for the name is thin you are getting different colors. i have fixed the code so you can see the border in Dreamweaver.

```html
<html>

<head>
<base target="_blank">
<style>
<!--
p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
{margin-top:0cm;
margin-right:0cm;
margin-bottom:0.0pt;
margin-left:0cm;
font-size:10.0pt;
font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";}
.Section1 p {
font-size: 9px;
font-weight: normal;
}
.disclaimer {
font-weight: bold;
 }
 -->
</style>

</head>

<body lang=EN-IN link=blue vlink=purple>

<div class=Section1>

<table class=MsoTableGrid border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0
 style='border-collapse:collapse;border:none'>
 <tr>
  <td width=274 valign=center style='width:152.4pt;border:none;border-right:2.25pt solid #414141;
  padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt'>
  <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0cm;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
  normal'><a href="http://www.casesbysource.com/"><span 
style='color:windowtext;text-decoration:none'><img border=0 width=202 height=62 
style="width:202px; height:62px" id="Picture 0"
  src="https://s4.postimg.org/cq9ledh4t/CBS-email-sig.jpg" alt="logo.jpg">
 </span></a></p>
  </td>
  <td width=338 valign=top style='width:202.5pt;border:none;padding:0cm 
5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt'>
  <table class=MsoTableGrid border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0
   style='border-collapse:collapse;border:none'>
   <tr>
    <td width=153 valign=top style='width:92.05pt;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm'>
    <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0cm;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    line-height:normal'><span style='font-size:12.0pt;color:#414141'>Mark 
DiSilvestro</span></p>
    <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0cm;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
line-height:normal'><span style='font-size:10pt; color:#1B3967'>COO</span>
</p>
    </td>
    <td width=154 valign=top style='width:92.15pt;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm'>
    <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0cm;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    line-height:normal'>&nbsp;</p>
    <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0cm;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    line-height:normal'>&nbsp;</p>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0cm;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
  normal'><span class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0cm;margin-
bottom:.0001pt;
    line-height:normal"><span style="font-size: 10pt; color: #414141">201-529-1069</span></span></p>
  <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0cm;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
  normal'><span style='font-size:10pt; color:#1B3967'><a
  href="http://www.casesbysource.com" style="text-decoration:none"><span 
style='color:#1B3967; text-decoration:
  none; font-size: 10pt;'>www.casesbysource.com</span></a><br>
215 Island Road, Mahwah, NJ 07430</span></p></tr>
  </table>
  <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0cm;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
  normal'></p>
  <p><br><br>
  </p>
  <p>
 <span class="disclaimer" span style='font-size:7.0pt; color:#000000; font-weight: normal;'>This e-mail is intended only for the addressee(s) and may contain confidential information.   If you are not the intended recipient, you are hereby notified that any use of this information or dissemination, distribution, or copying of this e-mail is strictly prohibited.  If you have received this e-mail in error, please notify the sender immediately by return e-mail and delete the original message.thank you</span>
</td>
 </tr>
</table>

<p class=MsoNormal>&nbsp;</p>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

**Something to note:**
Your signature is created in Outlook with a lot of outlook code. Try creating it using basic HTML so you can use it on any email client.